# Unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I created a windows in cocoa application and in window i inserted a text field.
In text filed I want to insert the "hello world" string. I have tried the code as

```
[self.textfieldvalue setStringValue:@"Hellow world"];
```

here the textfieldvalue is

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textfieldvalue;
```

that code is compiled successfully but when it is running throw the error

```
[NSWindow setStringValue:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080001e1f00
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is your `textfieldValue:` linked correctly in IB? Seems that it's linked to a NSWindow instead.

Comment: You send the message to an instance of NSWindow. Check the property.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the IB declaration to

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textfieldvalue;
```

and then connect to your text field because when you dragged the text field from your object library, you dragged a UITextField not NSTextfield.